# How can I arrange arbitrarily folders in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, sorting, desktop-customization

I want to sort some music folders by the release date, so I was wondering if there's a way to edit the metadata of the folder, because looking on the sort options, there's a "year" column, but I can't find a way to edit it.
Any help is appreciated, Thanks :D.

Comment: Yeah, but I think that's only for Office files, no? I want to do that with folders in the explorer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Windows, there is one "built-in" metadata element, `Comments`, available. Comments are added to a folder via a `desktop.ini` file within the folder. You'll find existing files in any folder that displays a custom icon.
Note that:

- When created by the OS, `desktop.ini` files have both their `Hidden` and `System` attributes set, which renders them "SupperHidden". For the files to be visible in **Explorer**, two options have to be set correctly in **Explorer**'s `View` options:

  - *Select* `"Show hidden files, folders, and drives"`
  - *Clear* `"Hide protected operating system files (Recommended)"`
- The files are plain text files with the `.ini` extension, and thus can be viewd/edited in **Notepad**
- The folder's `ReadOnly` attribute serves as a flag that tells Windows to process the desktop.ini file. If creating the files manually, you have to set this attribute via Command Prompt or PowerShell. It's quicker to assign a custom icon to a folder, the file will be created and the attribute set. If you don't want the custom icon, just delete those lines from the file when editing.
- A comment is specified by adding an `InfoTip=` line to the `[.ShellClassINfo]` section of the file (the section header will have been created if you assigned a custom icon):

  ```
   [.ShellClassInfo]
   InfoTip=1968
   IconResource=C:\WINDOWS\System32\SHELL32.dll,27
  ```

Then just add the `Comments` column to a `Details` view in **Explorer** and click the header to sort on that column,

Comment: Oh, ok ok, then I have to choose a custom icon for every folder, thanks for the help, one more thing, is there a way to change the name of the column? so instead of comments it says year or something like that?

Comment: You don't have to assign a custom icon, you can just create the file in **Notepad**. But then you have set the `ReadOnly` attribute via Command Prompt or PowerShell, as there's no way to do so via the UI.

Comment: Dude, props. kludgey though it may be, this is the first potentially viable solution to this request I've seen to date. nice

Comment: @FrankThomas: The process can be scripted for processing a large niumber of folders or to crreate a context menu entry. You can also take over other properties/columns available in **EXplorer** -- `Rating`, `Categories`, `Tags`, etc. via some registry editing combined with desktop.ini functionality. I'm pretty sure I've posated the detailed info before, bujt don't have a lilnk. Busy tommorow, so you might find it sooner seraching yourself. Not sure if I posted here,  StackOverflow, or TenForums(KeithM). I will search myself as well when I get a chance.